# Best way to check string and convert to int in c#

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, int, string-parsing

Please help me to improve my code.
The idea is:
 if string is ok 
    then convert to int

1- it does check just null or blank string

```
int t=0;
 if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.text.trim())
     t= int.Parse(textbox1.text.trim());
```

2-

```
if(int.tryparse(textbox1.text.trim(), out t)      
   t=int.Parse(textbox1.text.trim());
```

or shortif

```
 return string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.text.trim()) ? 0 :  int.Parse(textbox1.text.trim());
```

is there other better way?

Comment: What is your definition of "ok"?

Comment: If `textbox1.text` is `null` you will get `NullReferenceException` on `textbox1.text.trim()`. The check `!string.IsNullOrEmpty` won't help you.

Comment: Textbox1.Text is never null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to get user input and convert it to integers is through the [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This method has the advantage to not throw a costly  exception if the input is wrong (like Parse or Convert.ToInt32) but returns true or false allowing you to display a meaningful error message to your user.

```
int t;
if(Int32.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out t)
{
  // t has ben set with the integer converted
  // add here the code that uses the t variable
}
else
{
  // textbox1.Text doesn't contain a valid integer
  // Add here a message to your users about the wrong input....
  // (if needed)
}
```

Notice that textbox1.Text is never null so you don't need to explicitly check for it. Of couse I assume that this textbox1 is a TextBox control defined in your InitializeComponent call and thus is not null by itself.

Comment: it seem a IF block without body?

Comment: It was just an example. Instead of the comments just add the code that uses the t variable or a message to your users.

Comment: with your help:

Comment: thanks and with your help i think;

    class Program
     {
        public struct toInt
        {
           public int x;
           public bool y;    
        };

          static void Main()
           {
             toInt a;
             a= callcheckint();
            } 

        private toInt callcheckint()
         {
           toInt b;
           b.y=Int32.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out b.x);
            
            return b;
         }
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
int t = 0;
int.TryParse(textbox1?.Text?.Trim(), out t);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;

Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We need to Check whether TryParse returns true or Not. if true then it succeeds & false if any error occurs.The TryParse will return 0 for both if the TryParse is failed or actual string value is 0.

```
string s2 = "13.3";
int i;

//i = Convert.ToInt32(s2);                   // Run Time Error
Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse(s2, out i));  // False
Console.WriteLine(i);                        // Output will be 0

string s3 = "Hello";
//i = Convert.ToInt32(s2);                  // Run Time Error
Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse(s3, out i)); // False
Console.WriteLine(i);                       // Output will be 0

string s1 = null;
Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse(s1, out i));  // False
Console.WriteLine(i);                        // Output will be 0

string s4 = "0";      
Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse(s4, out i));  // return True
Console.WriteLine(i);                        // Output will be 0
```